# How to create a popover dialog using @reach/dialog

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accessibility

I want to create a popover dialog using [Reach UI](https://reach.tech/dialog) like [Reakit Non-modal Dialogs](https://reakit.io/docs/dialog/#non-modal-dialogs). Styling `DialogOverlay` and `DialogContent` seems to be not enough because the dialog is rendered inside a Portal in `body`: Setting `position: absolute` on `DialogContent` (or `DialogOverlay`) does not work because the dialog is rendered using a Portal in the `body`, so its position is relative to the entire page and not to its container element. [The PR 901](https://github.com/reach/reach-ui/pull/901) seems to address the issue. Is there any workaround to reach the result without forking the library?